# Best practice for micro-service joining

Tags: microservices

Case 1 one to many:

Card and User are 2 different micro-services

For example Each Card entity contains 1 UserID.

1. Frontend call 2 APIs sequencely (i.e. Call Card API -> Call User API by Card.UserID)
2. Card micro-service call User API by UserID and then return joined result. Frontend only need to call Card API

Which one is the best?

Case 2 many to many:
If I need to join many to many in 2 micro-services, what is the best practice?

Comment: You can also go with API gateway pattern https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in one line, the best practice is to avoid interdependencies between microservices.

Based on my experience I have listed below the options, which needs to be chosen based on the performance & fault tolerance that your system should meet

1. Your front end to call card api and then user api
2. Consider user service as a component - if your user service is always going to be consumed by another microservice, then this would be a better option